# Zeller's algorithm

Tags: javascript

I need to find which day it is when I put a date in the input using Zeller's algorithm. So this is how I've come so far. I've used the base code from my teacher, but when I put today's date in, it comes out Friday when it should be Wednesday instead.

```
var print = document.getElementById("print");

print.onclick = function () {
var D = document.getElementById("date").value;
var M = document.getElementById("month").value;
var Y = document.getElementById("year").value;
var C = document.getElementById("twoFirst").value;
var K = document.getElementById("twoLatest").value;
pOutput.innerHTML = dagFunction(D, M, Y, C, K);
}

function dagFunction(D, M, Y, C, K) {
if (M==1 || M==2) {
    M+=12;
    Y--;
return (M, Y)
}

var X = 2.6 * M - 5.39

if (X < 0) {
    X = Math.ceil(X) // X skal rundes opp
}
else {
    X = Math.floor(X) // X skal rundes ned
}

Y = Math.floor(K/4)
var Z = Math.floor(C/4)

var S = X + Y + Z + D + K - 2 * C
var R = S % 7

if (R==0) {
return "Søndag"
}
else if (R==1) {
return "Mandag"
}
else if (R==2) {
return "Tirsdag"
}
else if (R==3) {
return "Onsdag"
}
else if (R==4) {
return "Torsdag"
}
else if (R==5) {
return "Fredag"
}
else if (R==6) {
return "Lørdag"
}
}
```

Comment: Your best bet here is to use the powerful debugger built into your browser or IDE to step through the code and see where it's going wrong. Off the bat I can see a couple of errors. `value` is always a string, and so when you pass your `M` into `dagFunction`, the path where it does `M+=12` will append the characters 1 and 2 to the end of the string `M` (rather than adding 12 to a number). You need to convert those values to number before using them. Also, you have `return (M, Y)`; I'm not sure what you wanted that to do, but it's just a long way to write `return Y`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so i checked the console on my browser. And the M didn't pass through correctly. I even tried to add the parseFloat function on M but the part where it's gonna M + 12 won't work

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? If you call your function directly with something like `console.log(dagFunction(19, 9, 2018, 20, 18));` you'll see that it correctly outputs Wednesday. So the problem is most likely in your input and how you parse it. Keep in mind that `.value` is a string, so all of them have to be parsed with either `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.